# Can I leave onUpgrade() method empty if the database version is same?

Tags: android, sqlite

I made an app which uses sqlite database and the database version is 1 in DbHelper class. Also the app version is 1 in build.gradle. Suppose, I published the app and now I want to update that app with the app version 2. Firstly,  should I increase the db version too?  Is it mandatory even if the database structure is untouched? If it's mandatory then it's fine. I have done some searching on database upgrade and will get the help from there. But if it's not mandatory, then can I leave the `onUpgrade()` method empty?

To make it clear;

**versionCode 1  (build.gradle)**

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1
...

    @override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
            //empty
    }
```

**versionCode 2  (build.gradle)**

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; //if this is fine
...

@override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        //what should I do here?
    }
```

Comment: Yes, do not increase db Version. Yes, leave onUpgrade() empty, i.e. do not override it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it mandatory even if the database structure is untouched?

No. Only increment the database schema version when you change the schema (e.g., add columns, add tables, remove tables).

> But if it's not mandatory, then can I leave the onUpgrade() method empty?

Yes, though you might consider throwing an `IllegalStateException` in debug builds:

```
if (BuildConfig.IS_DEBUG) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

That way, in development and testing, you don't forget about `onUpgrade()` if you increment the schema version.

Comment: So that means if the database schema is not changed then I can leave the `onUpgrade()` method empty(or throw an `IllegalStateException` as you said). And this doesn't affect the old version(app) users' data on updating the application?

Comment: @NirajNiroula: Correct. From the standpoint of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass, nothing has changed.